# Match String in mysql columns

Tags: php, mysql

I want to match the string in mysql columns

```
$string = "XYZ London, UK";
```

Below is the database structure

```
id   city        state      street      Address
1    London      BBA        WER         UK
2    California  ZZZ        787         USA
3    London      XYZ        WER         UK
```

What I want is when I look for the string I should get the result for the id 1 and 3.

Comment: before asking question please explain your code what you have tried for this

Comment: We are not here to write the code for you please come back with a specific question about a search query or function

Comment: I have looked for the mysql functions like, MATCH, LOCATE, LIKE, but I am not sure these are the best way to achieve the result. I was using the LIKE but that does not give me the desired results

Comment: I don't need the code I want to know which would be the best way to achieve the result

Comment: @VishalParkash If you want to know what is the best solution than you would only get opinionated answers. However `LIKE` is mostly use in combination with `%`

Comment: @SuperDJ, but that does not serve my purpose, as LIKE would search for a specific string, I want to search any string that matches the columns

Comment: I'm not giving you the answer I'm only pointing in a direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `LIKE` and `OR` help you

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE 'XYZ London, UK' LIKE CONCAT('%',city,'%')
   OR 'XYZ London, UK' LIKE CONCAT('%',state,'%')
   OR 'XYZ London, UK' LIKE CONCAT('%',street,'%')
   OR 'XYZ London, UK' LIKE CONCAT('%',Address,'%')
```

or you also can use `INSTR` and `OR`

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE INSTR('XYZ London, UK',city)>0
   OR INSTR('XYZ London, UK',state)>0
   OR INSTR('XYZ London, UK',street)>0
   OR INSTR('XYZ London, UK',Address)>0;
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3c64d/5

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

```
$string= "XYZ London, UK";
if (strpos($db, $string) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Edit:SQl Query:

```
select * from table where column like  '%string%'
```

Comment: I need query not php function

Comment: what query?You mean the sql one?